# Mobile position of images in listview using jQuery 

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

If I add `<li class="ui-li-has-thumb">` and then add an image it places it on the left side of the `li`.

I have two more images. How do I place them on the right side of the `li`? Ideally they would be side-by-side and not one top of the other.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <% @pending_friends.each do |f| %>
        <li class="ui-li-has-thumb">
          <img class="ui-li-thumb" src="..." />
          <%= f.name %>
          <img class="accept" src="...." />
          <img class="decline" src="...." />

    <% end %>
</ul>
```

### EDIT

I know there's split button, but is there way to assign my last 2 images to the right?  Need 2 buttons, not 1

```
 -------------------------------------------
|  ------  ----------------------  -------  |
| | ui-  ||                      ||  what  ||
| | li-  ||    Main Content      ||   is   ||
| |thumb ||                      || class  ||
| |      ||                      ||  name  ||
|  ------  ----------------------  -------  |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you could try CSS float right?  <img class="accept" src="...." style="float:right;" /> <img class="decline" src="...." style="float:right;" />

Comment: float:right only takes you to the right side of the inner container.  Trying to find the class name of the outer right container.

Comment: do you have sufficient width for them? i tried and they appear side by side: http://jsfiddle.net/BthnC/

Comment: But do you see how the first img goes all the way to the left while the other images are in the center.  trying to find the class name that puts it on the right.  I updated question with more details

Answer (score 2):

Well this is what I came up with, Live Link

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/BthnC/6/

A nested navbar in the listview

```
<div data-role="page">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
        <li>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Title
                    </li>                    
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>                   
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/88-beermug.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png" />
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/18-envelope.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Title
                    </li>                    
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>                   
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/88-beermug.png" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/docs/toolbars/glyphish-icons/21-skull.png" />
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```